# Is it possible to transform an IObservable<T> to an IAsyncEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, signalr, system.reactive, iasyncenumerable

I have an observable `IObservable<T>` / `ISubject<T>` and want to return that by using SignalR. SignalR has the concept of async streams where you have to return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`.

How can I transform an `IObservable<T>` to an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension method in the `System.Linq.Async` assembly, available as a NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async).

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> ToAsyncEnumerable<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source);
```